# FIlter search results using NSPredicate

Tags: uitableview, ios7, xcode5

I have below array structure that I'm using as a **UITableview Datasource**.

Now I want to implement search bar and want to filter item_name using **NSPredicate**. Can any please guide me how should I filter **NSDictionaries** based on their item names?

```
- NSArray
  -NSdictionary
    -NSArray
      -NSdicationary
       {
         item_id = “1”
         item_name = “Pizza”
      }
     -NSdicationary
      {
        item_id = “2”
        item_name = “Burger”
     }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the enclosing array and dictionary? Is it possible to back your table view with a single array of dictionaries? If so, the predicate is trivially `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"item_name == %@", searchTerm]`.

Comment: Agreed with warrenm. You can use the predicate in its normal way if the data structure used to populate the table view is simpler. BTW rather than using `==` for comparison you can use `CONTAINS` keyword so that the search result will contain the terms which contains the keyword to be searched and not only those which are exactly matching.

Comment: Actually I have different section in Tableview and every first NSDictionary has an Array of Dictionaries for a section.